# Eigenstates and eigenvalues of the operator $xp+ px$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

It is a hermitian operator, right? So, what are its eigenstates and eigenvalues? It is known that it is the infinitesimal generator of the dilation group in 1d. But apparently, a nontrivial dilation operator has no eigenstate!

ps. The last statement is wrong.

Comment: How did you conclude this "But apparently..." bit?

Comment: Just intuitively, how could a function be invariant under dilation?

Comment: Act on $1/\sqrt x$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the spectrum of $\hat x \hat p + \hat p \hat x$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494715/)

Comment: More explicitly, $\exp (i\epsilon (\hat x \hat p + \hat p \hat x )/\hbar) x^{-1/2} = \exp (2\epsilon(1/2 + x\partial_x))  x^{-1/2}  = e^\epsilon \exp(2\epsilon \partial_{\ln x}) \exp(-\ln x /2)$  $= e^\epsilon \exp (-(\ln x + 2\epsilon )/2)= 1/\sqrt x$.

Comment: any other eigenstates?

Comment: Powers of *x*, of course.

Comment: Indeed! I am so stupid to recognize this. But these are really crazy eigenstates.

Comment: Yes, not normalizable.. none.